# how to update fig in matplotlib embedded in PyQt5?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5

I use a QComboBox to provide multiple choices. When a user change the choice, I obtain the currentText of the QComboBox. Then find the matched variable in the dataset, and make a boxplot and show the boxplot in a QWidget. When the choice is changed, the boxplot should be changed. However, the boxplot cannot be updated in the QWidget.

Following is the Stack.ui file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1318</width>
    <height>844</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tabDescrip">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Descriptive statistical analysis</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
          <item>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="labelType">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Property types</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBoxType">
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Rock properties</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
                <item>
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Oil properties</string>
                 </property>
                </item>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="labelName">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Property name</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBoxName"/>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="buttonPlot">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Plot</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QWidget" name="contentPlot" native="true">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
              <property name="autoFillBackground">
               <bool>true</bool>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1318</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Following is the codes.

```
from __future__ import division
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QApplication
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas

# load ui file
gui_file = 'Stack.ui'
[Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass] = uic.loadUiType(gui_file)

# create dataset
permeability = [4, 4, 2, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5]
porosity = [45, 45, 44.8, 46.5, 44.9, 45.7, 45, 44.7, 43.7, 46.5, 44.9, 43.5, 44.4, 43.4, 44.7, 44.7, 43.4, 44.7, 44.7]
temperature = [25, 25, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
oil_gravity = [47.61, 47.61, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69]
acid_number = [1.10, 3.4, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04]

d = {'permeability': permeability,
        'porosity': porosity,
        'temperature': temperature,
        'oil gravity': oil_gravity,
        'acid number': acid_number
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
global DF_global
DF_global = df

# define a class
class MainBody(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # check property types change
        self.comboBoxType.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.PropertyName)

        # set initial property name
        propertyType = self.comboBoxType.currentText()
        if propertyType == 'Rock properties':
            self.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.comboBoxName.addItems(['porosity', 'permeability', 'temperature'])

        # click the button to make a plot
        self.buttonPlot.clicked.connect(self.DescripPlot)


    # set property name when property types are changed
    def PropertyName(self):
        propertyType = self.comboBoxType.currentText()
        if propertyType == 'Rock properties':
            self.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.comboBoxName.addItems(['porosity', 'permeability', 'temperature'])
        else:
            self.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.comboBoxName.addItems(['oil gravity', 'acid number'])

   # descriptive plot
    def DescripPlot(self):
        # obtain current choice
        PropertyName_chosen = self.comboBoxName.currentText()
        # find the matched variable in imported dataset, the dataset is imported in other function
        array_col = DF_global[PropertyName_chosen].to_numpy()
        # remove nan from array to make plot
        filtered_array_col = array_col[~np.isnan(array_col)]

        # make a boxplot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        ax.boxplot(filtered_array_col)

        # put plot on QtWidgets
        self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(fig)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.contentPlot)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.plotWidget)

app = QApplication([])
first = MainBody()
first.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You cannot set *another* layout if one is already set. It's difficult to be sure, as your code is not a proper [mre], but it's possible that `self.contentPlot` already has a layout, otherwise your code will probably work only the first time the button is pressed, but not anymore (for the above reason). I'd suggest you to [edit] your question and provide the original UI file.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Could you please share how to upload the UI file and dataset file?

Comment: The UI is a simple XML file, so just open it with a basic text editor and copy its contents (please *always* do some basic research on the formats you're using, you cannot do programming if you don't know what you're using). The dataset is another story: your code is missing important aspects (what is `DF_global`?) so we cannot really help you. Please do the proper research to understand how to properly provide valid data in a MRE.

Comment: I provided the link to obtain the UI file and dataset. The codes are now reproducible. Any guidance or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: No, questions should be self contained, and not rely on external resources that could become unavailable and then make the question invalid. As already said, the UI is an XML file, so just add it to the question, then just create a basic dataset with a simple list of lists.

Comment: Thanks. As required, I provide the UI file and create a dataset within the codes.